# codeigniter update root directory

Tags: codeigniter

When trying to reference a function in my controller, I get the following error.  It's missing the "/angular/" in the path.  How can I update the root path to include the angular directory?

[image: url]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` at the beginning of wherever you are trying to call your function, placing `./` might also work.